# How can I build the Perl extension XML::Sablotron?

Tags: perl

I am getting errors when trying to install [XML::Sablotron](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML%3a%3aSablotron). What do I need to do to successfully build this module?

#### `perl -V`

```
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 14 subversion 2) configuration:
Platform:
osname=cygwin, osvers=1.7.15(0.26053), archname=cygwin-thread-multi-64int
uname='cygwin_nt-5.1 winxp 1.7.15(0.26053) 2012-05-09 10:25 i686 cygwin '
config_args='-de -Dlibperl=cygperl5_14.dll -Dcc=gcc-4 -Dld=g++-4 -Darchname=                       i686-cygwin-threads-64int -Dmksymlinks -Dusethreads -Accflags=-g'
hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
use64bitint=define, use64bitall=undef, uselongdouble=undef
usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
Compiler:
cc='gcc-4', ccflags ='-DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -g -fno-stric                       t-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector',
optimize='-O3',
cppflags='-DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -g -fno-strict-aliasing -                       pipe -fstack-protector'
ccversion='', gccversion='4.5.3', gccosandvers=''
intsize=4, longsize=4, ptrsize=4, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=12
ivtype='long long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lsee                       ksize=8
alignbytes=8, prototype=define
Linker and Libraries:
ld='g++-4', ldflags =' -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl                       ,--enable-auto-image-base -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib'
libpth=/usr/local/lib /usr/lib /lib
libs=-lgdbm -ldb -ldl -lcrypt -lgdbm_compat
perllibs=-ldl -lcrypt
libc=/usr/lib/libc.a, so=dll, useshrplib=true, libperl=cygperl5_14.dll
gnulibc_version=''
Dynamic Linking:
dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=dll, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags=' '
cccdlflags=' ', lddlflags=' --shared  -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--export-                       all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl):
Compile-time options: MULTIPLICITY PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
                    PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT PERL_PRESERVE_IVUV
                    PERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV USE_64_BIT_INT USE_ITHREADS
                    USE_LARGE_FILES USE_PERLIO USE_PERL_ATOF
                    USE_REENTRANT_API
 Locally applied patches:
    Bug#55162 File::Spec::case_tolerant performance
    CYG07 $vendorarch/auto/.rebase
    CYG15 static Win32CORE
    CYG17 cyg-1.7 paths-utf8
    0c612ce82 Fix building static extensions on cygwin, -UUSEIMPORTLIB
    1bac5ecc1 Fix 64-bit threading sv.c: S_anonymise_cv_maybe
    Cygwin::sync_winenv added
Built under cygwin
Compiled at Jul 12 2012 14:17:21
@INC:
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14
/usr/lib/perl5/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int
/usr/lib/perl5/5.14
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8
```

The Cygwin version is 2.774. there is the problem with [pango library](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=30388786) but i think it is not a problem of the following

The errors I get when I try to build `XML::Sablotron` (after `perl makeFile.PL`):

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/XML-Sablotron-1.01/DOM'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/XML-Sablotron-1.01/DOM'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/XML-Sablotron-1.01/Situation'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/XML-Sablotron-1.01/Situation'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/XML-Sablotron-1.01/SXP'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/XML-Sablotron-1.01/SXP'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/XML-Sablotron-1.01/Processor'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/XML-Sablotron-1.01/Processor'
gcc-4 -c    -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -g -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -   fstack-protector -DUSEIMPORTLIB -O3    -DVERSION=\"1.01\"  -DXS_VERSION=\"1.01\"  "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int/CORE"  -DPERL_POLLUTE Sablotron.c
In file included from Sablotron.xs:88:0:
DOM/DOM.h: In Funktion »__createNodeOld«:
DOM/DOM.h:90:17: Warnung: Typkonvertierung von Zeiger auf Ganzzahl anderer Breite
In file included from Sablotron.xs:88:0:
DOM/DOM.h: In Funktion »__checkNodeInstanceData«:
DOM/DOM.h:120:22: Warnung: Typkonvertierung in Zeiger von Ganzzahl anderer Breite
DOM/DOM.h: In Funktion »__createNodeNew«:
DOM/DOM.h:153:5: Warnung: Typkonvertierung von Zeiger auf Ganzzahl anderer Breite
In file included from Sablotron.xs:89:0:
Processor/Processor.h: In Funktion »MessageHandlerMakeCodeStub«:
Processor/Processor.h:122:7: Fehler: »sv_undef« undeclared (first use in this function)
Processor/Processor.h:122:7: Anmerkung: each undeclared identifier is reported only     
once for each function it appears in
Processor/Processor.h: In Funktion »MessageHandlerLogStub«:
...
In file included from Sablotron.xs:91:0:
Situation/Situation.h: In Funktion »_SV2SXP_Node«:
Situation/Situation.h:113:19: Warnung: Typkonvertierung in Zeiger von Ganzzahl anderer     
Breite
./DOM/DOM.xsh: In Funktion »XS_XML__Sablotron__DOM_parse«:
./DOM/DOM.xsh:53:30: Warnung: Typkonvertierung in Zeiger von Ganzzahl anderer Breite
....
(the same error for Processor/Processor.xsh and Situation/Situation.xsh)
```

Surely the best way is to use not the Sablotron. But because of time, I would prefer not to change everything.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Are you on 64-bit Windows? What version? There isn't a 64 bit version of Cygwin so I don't understand what 32 vs 64 refer to. What is the output of `perl -V`? What is the error you're getting? Show a small program that exhibits the problem so others can try.

Comment: Sorry for inaccuracy in the question. I've changed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just exhibited a very dangerous trait. You took an error such as:

```
Processor/Processor.h: In Funktion »MessageHandlerMakeCodeStub«:
Processor/Processor.h:122:7: Fehler: »sv_undef« undeclared
```

and made a series of unwarranted assumptions and arrived at the conclusions that 1) The problem is Cygwin and Windows specific; and 2) The problem is caused by the fact that `perl` is configured with `use64bitint=define`; and 3) The solution is to change integer sizes. (BTW, what's up with the mixture of German and English in error messages?)

I just tried to install [XML::Sablotron](http://search.cpan.org/XML::Sablotron) on my OSX 10.8 laptop with my [perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/App::perlbrew)ed `perl` and MacPorts built `sablotron` library.

[Searching Google for `sv_undef`](https://www.google.com/search?q=perl+sv_undef) leads one to the topic [Old CPAN modules with sv_undef](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=227161) which leads to [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/ExtUtils::MakeMaker):

> `POLLUTE`
>
> Release 5.005 grandfathered old global symbol names by providing preprocessor macros for extension source compatibility. As of release 5.6, these preprocessor definitions are not available by default. The `POLLUTE` flag specifies that the old names should still be defined:
>
> ```
>   perl Makefile.PL POLLUTE=1
> ```
>
> Please inform the module author if this is necessary to successfully install a module under 5.6 or later.

Unfortunately, that simple solution did not result in a successful build.

Instead, use [Devel::PPPort](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Devel::PPPort) to generate a `ppport.h` which you can use to generate patches based on your system.

This has nothing to do with Cywgin or 32 vs 64 bit. Your problem has to do with the fact that `XML::Sablotron` uses something that was deprecated [a long time ago](http://markmail.org/message/lvgwrrxdkcgn2s3h).

Comment: thank you very much for your investigation and time!Perhaps I should rethink about using Sablotron